# Why do I get an "XMLHttpRequest cannot load" error when I try to load an external JSON API into my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My javascript code with jquery is

```
$("#quoteid").on("click", function() {
    $.getJSON("http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&key=457653&format=json&lang=en", function(quotejson) {
        $("#quotegot").html(quotejson["quoteText"]);
   });
});
```

The ID "quoteid" is linked with a button in the page and the #quotegot is linked with a text box. Whenever I run the code, and press the button, a message in the console is displayed which says that

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&key=457653&format=json&lang=en. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access.

Whatever API I use, I get the same error. What should I do?

Comment: It's a CORS issue - you need to get the data server side

Comment: It means that the URL you're calling does not send CORS headers back with the response. If they also don't support JSONP format, then you cannot make a request to that API through JS

Comment: `&format=jsonp` - the callback function name needs to be sent using the query parameter name `jsonp` - see jquery documentation on how to set the callback parameter name